# OpenOffice Eclipse plugin doesn't recognize OpenOffice SDK

Tags: eclipse, openoffice.org, uno

I've installed OpenOffice 4.0 (application and SDK) in Ubuntu, because I want to develop OOo addons. When I attempt to create a new UNO project with Eclipse, it asks for both OpenOffice's and SDK's location. The plugin correctly recognizes the OpenOffice installation, but complains that "SDK version has to be at least 2.0.4" when given the SDK's path. The same issue happens with LibreOffice.

Is there a way to make Eclipse recognize OpenOffice 4 SDK to create a new UNO project?

OpenOffice was install as DEB files from Apache OpenOffice download page. The URL used to install the OpenOffice plugin is: http://www.openoffice.org/api/Projects/EclipseIntegration/dev-update/site.xml

Answer (score 2):

Searched a lot and finally found an alternate update site where it works.

Update Site:http://drake79.users.sourceforge.net/ooeclipse/site

Reference: http://www.flattermann.net/2009/06/openofficeorg-extension-development-with-eclipse-ooeclipse/#more-369

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Imho should be marked as answer